# How much memory do VueJS components use if they are not bound to a DOM element?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a simple Laravel application with three routes: `/page1`, `/page2`, and `/page3`.

Each of these pages will have a root VueJS component, and a substantial tree of sub-components.  Most of the sub-components will be specific to their page, but a few will be shared across pages.

I am using Laravel UI boilerplate, so that means ES6, single-page VueJS components, NPM and Webpack.

As far as I can see, I have two options for structuring the VueJS application.  The first option would be to create an entry point for each page (`page1.js`, `page2.js`, and `page3.js`). The problem with this approach is that any code for the shared components is duplicated across the compiled assets.  (I realise that I can configure Webpack to de-duplicate, but I'd rather not have to touch Webpack at all).

The other option would be to have a single entry point, `app.js`.  This file would instantiate three different Vue instances, binding each to a different DOM element, `#app-1`, `#app-2`, `#app-3`.  Each of my pages would then have only its respective DOM element.  The question is, however, how much client memory will the unbound Vue instances consume?

For example, if the web page contains `#app-1`, then `#app-2` and `#app-3` will remain unbound.  I would expect them to take some *some* memory, but will they take up an amount proportional to a simple Vue instance only, or proportional to their entire tree of sub-components?

Comment: Give it a try and see? This is a very broad question, and given you have no control over the client side, not really possible to answer except in the most general sense.

Comment: You could lazily instantiate the Vue components as they are needed.